# Move resource in AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-api-gateway

I would like to move a few resources one level above such as:

```
\v1\test1 -> \test1
\v2\test2 -> \test2
```

The documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-resource.html) say that it is possible. But when I run the following command:

```
aws apigateway  update-resource \
--rest-api-id xvxi2smff9 \
--resource-id 2r0epq \
--cli-input-json "{\"patchOperations\" : [ 
      {
        \"op\" : \"move\",
        \"path\" : \"eysorw\",
        \"value\" : \"2r0epq\",
        \"from\" : \"xvxi2smff9\"
      } 
]}"
```

I get the error that it is an invalid patch operation.

```
A client error (BadRequestException) occurred when calling the UpdateResource operation: Invalid patch operation specified. Must be 'add'|'remove'|'replace'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can "reparent" a resource by issuing a `replace` patch operation to the `/parentId` path with the resourceId of the new parent:

```
aws apigateway update-resource \
   --rest-api-id xvxi2smff9 \
   --resource-id 2r0epq \
   --patch-operations op=replace,path=/parentId,value=eysorw
```

[edited to replace patchOperations with patch-operations - comment to meet 6 character minimum edit]

Comment: to who falls prey to this like me, it's `patch-operations`, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-resource.html